# how to upgrade system's emacs on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: emacs

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.8.4-x86_64-linode31 x86_64)
$ emacs --version
=> 23.4.1
$ which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs
```

How to upgrade the emacs of system to 24.3?

Answer (score 5):

No need for new repositories -- just install the `emacs24` package(s) you want.

From a 12.10 system of mine:

```
edd@max:~$ COLUMNS=80 dpkg -l | grep "^ii  emacs"                           
ii  emacs-goodies- 35.2ubuntu2  all          Miscellaneous add-ons for Emacs
ii  emacs23-bin-co 23.4+1-4ubun amd64        The GNU Emacs editor's shared, ar
ii  emacs23-common 23.4+1-4ubun all          The GNU Emacs editor's shared, ar
ii  emacs23-common 23.4+1-1     all          GNU Emacs shared, architecture in
ii  emacs23-lucid  23.4+1-4ubun amd64        The GNU Emacs editor
ii  emacs24        24.1+1-2ubun amd64        GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ user 
ii  emacs24-bin-co 24.1+1-2ubun amd64        GNU Emacs editor's shared, archit
ii  emacs24-common 24.1+1-2ubun all          GNU Emacs editor's shared, archit
ii  emacs24-common 24.1+1-1     all          GNU Emacs common non-DFSG items, 
ii  emacsen-common 2.0.3        all          Common facilities for all emacsen
edd@max:~$
```

So just `sudo apt-get install emacs24` plus whichever additonal packages you like. This allows emacs23 and emacs24 to coexist, with emacs23 providing the default. (Which you can override, see `man dpkg-alternatives`).

Comment: so the step is:
1. COLUMNS=80 dpkg -l | grep "^ii  emacs"
2. apt-get install emacs24
?

Comment: No, just `sudo apt-get install emacs24`.  What I did was just for display.  You can of course also use `aptitude`, or the Ubuntu Software Center, or whatever other interface to the package system you use.

Comment: Ah...Thank you for sharing this! It seems dpkg did not provide the latest emacs.

Comment: For this task, you may have confused `dpkg` with something like `apt-cache search emacs`. Try that.

Comment: I will check and give it a try. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel How is this an answer?  The OP clearly asked for Emacs **24.3**, which is obviously **not** present in the standard repositories.

Comment: Sure, that is true in the very narrow sense, but emacs24 clearly is present. His whole question-and-self-answer is a little weak in general.

Answer (score 3):

## add [Damien Cassou’s emacs snapshot PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cassou/emacs
```

## update packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

## install emacs 24.3

```
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot-el emacs-snapshot-gtk emacs-snapshot
```

## remove old emacs

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Well, first off the OP asked for emacs 24, not snapshot. Second, emacs 24 *is* already in his Ubuntu release.

Comment: OK... How will you suggest I edit my answer?

Comment: Well ... see my answer, and comments. I think at this point you should just delete this own-answer attempt.

Comment: OK. I think we leave both answers. I am new to Linux. So dpkg, apt-cache is new to me. I need more time to study then use it. For now I will stick to simple (simple for me) solution to upgrade the emacs. Thanks!

Comment: That is not how the site works.  This answer is not appropriate and misleading.  Moreover, it is a little odd that you seem to refuse to upvote my answer.

Comment: Well, 24.3 is not present in quantal's repository, so installing `emacs24` package from `ppa:cassou/emacs` is probably the easiest way to get it.